# Spring - Mapping multiple url-pattern

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I've asked something few days ago about this, but now came a new problem. My webpage need to access to these urls:

```
/product/* //(this will be an id or anything else)
/shopcart/* //(GET, ADD...)
/*.html
```

I have to access to different HTML pages for some webapp information. At the webapp, you can ask for some products by `id` and you can see a detailed webpage with all his specs. Also, I have a shopping cart where you can add the products and each time you add a product it will be saved at server's session.

If I want to recover information about products in cart, I access to `/shopcart/get` and get all information into JSON format. I have this config into my web.xml for that:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/product/*</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/shopcart/*</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

The problem comes that I can access to `/product/1` to get all specs from product `1`, but I get the same if I use `/shopcart/1`. If I specify `@RequestMapping("product")` (e.g.) into my controller I will have to access to `/product/product/1` and I don't want that. How can I resolve this problem?

These are my controllers:

```
@Controller
public class ProductController {

    @RequestMapping("{id}")
    public ModelAndView get(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, @PathVariable String id) {
        Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        //data recovering
        return new ModelAndView("product", model);
    }
}

@Controller
public class CartController {

    @Autowired
    private JacksonConverter JacksonConverter;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/shopcart/get", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void get(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse) {
        // data recovering
        httpServletResponse.setContentType("application/json; charset=utf-8");
        httpServletResponse.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        httpServletResponse.getWriter().print(json);
    }
}
```

Comment: map the dispatcher to `/` and use annotations to map each controller/methods to their url(s)

Comment: I'm dissapointed :/ I was trying to find a way to solve my problem with my configuration when the most easy way was there all the time, but now I can't access to my CSS and JS resources :S and they are not into my `WEB-INF`

Answer (score 3):

I got the soluiton for this problem.

First of all, thanks to **[RC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/180100/rc)** for his answer in comments. The proper way that I wanted to use to access to my urls will be solved easily changing my `servlet-mapping` in my `web.xml` to this:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

And adding proper paths to my Controllers like this:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("product")
public class ProductController {

    @RequestMapping("{id}")
    public ModelAndView get(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, @PathVariable String id) {
        ...
    }

@Controller
@RequestMapping("shopcart")
public class CartController {

    @Autowired
    private JacksonConverter JacksonConverter;

    @RequestMapping(value = "get", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void get(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse) {
        ...
    }
```

But this isn't all you need. In my case, I couldn't load my `CSS` and `JS` resources. So, you need to specify to Spring where are your resorces, adding this into your servlet configuration (`dispatcher-servlet.xml` in my case):

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/"/>
```

The `/resources` url must be changed on where your resources are. Now, you only have to add this into your JSP pages and all your resources will be loaded:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/css/main.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/js/main.js"></script>
```

Link to resources solution: **[Spring can't load my css files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20832533/spring-cant-load-my-css-files)**

**Tip**: If you are moving your `CSS` and `JS` resources into a folder, like `/resources/css` and `/resources/js`, don't forget to build your project again, because your webpages will not access them.