# Issues with mapping multiple controllers

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am new to spring.My mappings not working correctly though my Tomcat logs show that my URL is mapped.

```
INFO: Mapped URL path [/movie/{name}] onto handler 'movieController'
Jun 21, 2015 9:03:24 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/movie/{name}.*] onto handler 'movieController'
Jun 21, 2015 9:03:24 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/movie/{name}/] onto handler 'movieController'
Jun 21, 2015 9:03:24 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/movies] onto handler 'movieController'
Jun 21, 2015 9:03:24 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/movies.*] onto handler 'movieController'
Jun 21, 2015 9:03:24 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/movies/] onto handler 'movieController'
Jun 21, 2015 9:03:24 PM **org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/employeelist] onto handler 'userList'
Jun 21, 2015 9:03:24 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/employeelist.*] onto handler 'userList'
Jun 21, 2015 9:03:24 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/employeelist/] onto handler 'userList'
```

I have two controllers defined in web.xml.

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

    <display-name>Spring Web MVC Application</display-name>


    <servlet>       <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>    </servlet>

    <!-- for ListDispatcher -->

    <servlet>       <servlet-name>list-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>    </servlet>


    <servlet-mapping>       <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/test/*</url-pattern>  </servlet-mapping>


    <servlet-mapping>       <servlet-name>list-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/list/*</url-pattern>  </servlet-mapping>


<context-param>   <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>  
<param-value>
    /WEB-INF/list-dispatcher-servlet.xml
    /WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml   </param-value> </context-param>

    <!-- <listener>
<listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
        </listener> --> 
</web-app>
```

I am getting output for the ones defined in MovieController.
http://localhost:8080/SpringMVC/test/movies

But when i giving the URL to fetch the employeelist(another controller).its not working.Below is the controller class.:-

```
@Controller

public class UserList {


    public ModelAndView getdata() {
        System.out.println("Data");

        ArrayList<Employee> list = getEmpList();

        //return back to index.jsp
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("index");
        model.addObject("lists", list);

        return model;

    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/employeelist", method = RequestMethod.GET) 
    public @ResponseBody  ArrayList<Employee> getEmpList(){
        System.out.println("inside The ArrayList");
        ArrayList<Employee> emp=new ArrayList<Employee>();
        emp.add(new Employee("sougata",25));
        emp.add(new Employee("sahil",30));
        return emp;

    }
}
```

Can someone pleas help me out to get the response from the 2nd controller.
URL i am using is:-
http://localhost:8080/SpringMVC/list/employeelist

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the piece of snippet code in your application.

In your case, You have separated two controller's for multiple action. So according to your case scenario, replace this snippet code in web.xml, like this

```
<servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

And change the controller request mapping in the controller class,
for movie Controller add like this,

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/movieController")
public class MovieController {
```

for userList controller add like this,

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/userListController")
public class UserList {
```

Check your component-base package property correctly mentioned in dispatcher-servlet.xml.

Comment: Currently when i am trying o hit this URL :-http://localhost:8080/SpringMVC/userListController/employeelist
its printing the test lines but unable to return the json. below is the error i am getting.

"The resource identified by this request is only capable of generating responses with characteristics not acceptable according to the request "accept" headers. its entering the method but unable to print the json."Can you suggest please,

Comment: Try this,, This will help you get json object in the response. Add ResponseBody annotation in your method... @RequestMapping(value = "/methodURL", method = RequestMethod.GET or POST, headers="Accept=application/json")
public @ResponseBody methodName {

Comment: @RequestMapping(value="/employeelist", method = RequestMethod.GET,headers="Accept=application/json") 
 public @ResponseBody  ArrayList<Employee> getEmpList(){
  System.out.println("inside The ArrayList");
  ArrayList<Employee> emp=new ArrayList<Employee>();
  emp.add(new Employee("sougata",25));
  emp.add(new Employee("sahil",30));
  return emp;
  
 }

Comment: Are you request to return the response to same page or different page? are you hitting the URL to get the response or passing an ajax request?

Comment: i am trying to return just the json on the same page.                                             http://localhost:8080/SpringMVC/userListController/employeelist                          Its showing no matching handler found for servlet request :path 'userListController/employeelist',method 'GET' ,parameters map[[empty]]

Comment: @ResponseBody annotation will return you a JSON Object on the same page. It depends on your requirement how are you gonna handle it in the front end.

Comment: what will the url pattern for the 2nd controller                                                                 <servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>list-dispatcher</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/list/*</url-pattern></servlet-mapping>   
is this ok??

Comment: Use like this in web.xml `<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>` For 2nd Controller requestMapping differentiate in the HTTP Request when you are making any request. Are you still getting an error??

Comment: Yes Vignesh,i am still getting the error.the issue i think is with the 2nd controller.:(

Answer (score 0):

Try adding produces="application/json" to your @RequestMapping as shown below.

@RequestMapping(value="/employeelist", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces="application/json")

Comment: seems the issue is with the initialization of the second controller.
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/SpringMVC/userListController/employeelist] in DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc-dispatcher'.
The name here should be list-dispatchet-servlet not mvc-dispatcher.

Comment: Also i have added
  @RequestMapping(value ="/employeelist", method = RequestMethod.GET,headers="Accept=application/json")

produces isn't applicable here.

Comment: Are you still able to see the below test/debug line after hitting the URL? 
inside The ArrayList

Comment: when i am giving this                                                                                            @RequestMapping(value ="/employeelist", method = RequestMethod.GET) i am able to see the test line.    However i get the 406 error in the browser.                                                                      But once I add      
                                                                                                                      @RequestMapping(value ="/employeelist", method = RequestMethod.GET,headers="Accept=application/json"),i dnt see the test line again.

Comment: can you please share your model class Employee here

Comment: package pojo;

public class Employee {
 String name;
 int age;
 public Employee(String name, int age) {
  super();
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
 }
 public String getName() {
  return name;
 }
 public void setName(String name) {
  this.name = name;
 }
 public int getAge() {
  return age;
 }
 public void setAge(int age) {
  this.age = age;
 }

 

}also in the logs it says initialized mvc-dispatcher servlet.i alo have list dispatcher servlet but it's not in logs

Comment: <servlet>
  <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>

Comment: Keyur Vyas
Can you provide a sample program containing multiple controllers in web.xml. If it is possible from your side,that will help.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to integrate spring MVC and CXF service?
the servlet-class for list-dispatcher is CXFServlet in your web.xml.
 org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet
If not-You do not actually need two different servlet configurations.
simply have the below

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
    version="2.4">
    <servlet><servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: <servlet>
  <servlet-name>list-dispatcher</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>
 <servlet>
  <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>
what is the problem here.i am unable to get response from second controller

Comment: what is the url patter in each mapping? and did the above config with a common servlet mapping worked for you?

Comment: for MovieController its <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>                                          for UserListController its  <url-pattern>/list/</url-pattern>                            below links are working.                                        
http://localhost:8080/SpringMVC/movieController/movie/pk                                                               http://localhost:8080/SpringMVC/movieController/movies/name                            
**************for UserListController****************
tried this one.not working   
localhost:8080/SpringMVC/userListController/employeelist

Comment: Refer this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21942486/spring-mapping-multiple-url-pattern
You need to change the servlet-mapping in your web.xml. And one note, in your case it is not about two different controllers, it is two different URL mappings which can always be in the same controller as well.