# Programmatically loading resources using Spring MVC after context init?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I've been using Spring to assist me with developing an internal tool for a company. I've never used Spring before until a couple weeks ago. Work is breezing by with how great and easy to use Spring is! But I came to a screeching halt about two-three days ago on a question that I cannot seem to find any documentation to. I don't even know if you could do it without using hacks of some sort?

How can you programmatically load resources say CSS, JavaScript, and a collection of various media files using the Spring MVC framework after the context has been initialized?

*[I do apologize if this question has been asked before, I couldn't find anything during my search.]* Thank you kindly for all your help and time!

P.S. I've tried dynamically mapping it via **<mvc:resource />** tag with **SPEL** in the application context and failed miserably as I realized Spring hands these mappings off to **ResourceHandlerRegistry** instance when the application context is initialized. I've also tried creating a Interceptor that would autowire the **ResourceHandlerRegistry** instance to it and load the required resources dynamically during a HTTP Request but discovered you cannot autowire the **ResourceHandlerRegistry** instance.

Comment: It's quite straightforward, with the `getResource` method on the `ApplicationContext`, although I suspect that's not all you're looking to do, i.e. this is an [XY](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378) problem. Are you really looking to just load some text into code?

Comment: See if this helps - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20832533/spring-cant-load-my-css-files

Comment: @kolossus That is something I tried but I'm not quite sure on how to inject the resource to ResourceHandlerRegistry so I could use it within a view when loading CSS and JavaScript files. The tool has a couple different themes *(which have different styles and behaviors)* that the controller specifies during a HTTP request. Something like new ModelAndView("default.index"); would map to the view index under the theme "default". I hope that makes pretty good sense on what I'm trying to accomplish here?

Comment: I found this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=71NVb3vMvMc *(Spring Developer)* but I don't quite understand their intentions with the examples being used in it?